# I can't start ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, resize

Please help me with what are the steps to recover my system at the 100% of power. I suspect that I need to resize the boot partition, but I do not have experience to do it.

Paste from boot-repair at Sun, 11 Oct 2015 19:41:56 +0000:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/12758007/

Thanks.

Marcelo

Answer (score 0):

[Gparted status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTAZJ.png)

This is the last status shot screen. Maybe help to resolve my previous "ask ubuntu" I can't start ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Please edit your original post to inculed this with what you are trying to do an the issues that you are having with partitioning in gparted.

Comment: OK, I will start a new "Ask Question"